# How do I use Riot Games API with an API key?

Tags: python, rest, riot-games-api

I was trying to connect to the Riot Games API with the Python requests module, and it keeps giving me a 401 error. I added an API key, but it still says unauthorized. If anyone knows what is wrong with the code it would be appreciated.

I have tried tinkering and all I have this code:

```
import os
import requests

API_KEY = os.getenv("riot-key")

URL = "https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot"

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + API_KEY
}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
else:
    print("Request failed with status code:", response.status_code)
```

All I really have concluded is that the API key itself is not the issue, it is the request call.

Comment: You may need to include your api key as a parameter rather than a header. Try it: use a ? after your initial endpoint. https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot?api_key=<key>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It looks like](https://hextechdocs.dev/getting-started-with-the-riot-games-api/) Riot Games API uses the header `X-Riot-Token` to pass the authentication token, not `Authorization`, for some reason.

```py
import os
import requests

API_KEY = os.getenv("riot-key")

URL = "https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot"

headers = {
    "X-Riot-Token": API_KEY
}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
else:
    print("Request failed with status code:", response.status_code)
```

You can also pass the API key as a query string parameter, however this can be slightly less secure in some scenarios.

```
import os
import requests

API_KEY = os.getenv("riot-key")

URL = "https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot?api_key=" + API_KEY

response = requests.get(URL)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
else:
    print("Request failed with status code:", response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your api key as a parameter rather than a header.

```
https://americas.api.riotgames.com/riot/?api_key=YOUR-API-KEY
```

Here is some help I found: [https://apipheny.io/riot-games-api/#:~:text=All%20API%20calls%20to%20Riot,re%20making%20the%20request%20on](https://apipheny.io/riot-games-api/#:%7E:text=All%20API%20calls%20to%20Riot,re%20making%20the%20request%20on).