# How to get schema of headers in REST API

Tags: python, rest, riot-games-api

I wanted to play with LeagueOfLegends API to get some data from my games.
I know I can append some params to the url like
`https://europe.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/` -> `https://europe.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/my_nickname/my_tag?api_key=123456` but I prefer to use headers so:

```
url = https://europe.api.riotgames.com/riot/account/v1/accounts/by-riot-id/
headers = {
   'params': {
      'name': my_name,
      'tag': my_tag,
      }
   'api_key': 123456
   }
```

In this question we can see that `api_key` param is named `X-Riot-Token` but how can I find out what are the keywords and their structure in headers?
[How do I use Riot Games API with an API key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75338720/how-do-i-use-riot-games-api-with-an-api-key)

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a bit more? Have you tried calling the url with curl or api testing tool postman/isomania tool?

Comment: I just want to know if somehow I can check what are possible keys that I can have in headers if there is no such info in documentation online. For example if I run `response = request.get(url)` is there a key that will return me all of the possible params in headers? like `response['show_headers']

Comment: Run curl -v w url onh ti terminal. It will print the headers.  Posting as answer. Please have a look.

Comment: What describes the header that can be used is actually the API. That's what an API is: a description of a communication interface. Many people confuse it with a service implementing an API though.

Answer (score 0):

there's no way to request the full list of headers from an api other than if you send the proper request and they return those headers. The same goes for query parameters, without docs, it's trial and error to find all the possible combinations.

Regarding the api you are using.

- the `gameName` for League of Legends is `lol`
- the `tagLine` is a string value, which I believe is equivalent to the `Riot ID`

> A Riot ID is comprised of two parts: your in-game name and a hashtag followed by three-to-five numbers or letters.

*src: https://developer.riotgames.com/apis#account-v1/GET_getByRiotId*

apparently, you can access their OpenAPI description on your local machine with the following. This *should* have all query and header parameter definitions for their apis.

`curl -k https://127.0.0.1:2999/swagger/v3/openapi.json`

Comment: gameName is actually the "(in)Game name" and tagline is the discriminator of this ingame name. The Riot Id is structured like this: gameName#tagLine - please don't enter "lol" as a gameName. The swagger api is only for the local game api, not the one sitting api.riotgames.com.